# Undefined Variables in row

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I am newbie to php. I am using dreamweaver to write the php. I need to develop a system for customer ordering system for my Coursework. I wish to display the product to customer but it can't work. It ask for defined variables in row. 
Here is the 
undefined variables in row for : 
name, description and price.

here the code

```
            <td><img src="<?=$row['picture']?>" /></td>
        <td>    <b><?=$row['name']?></b><br />
                <?=$row['description']?><br />
                Price:<big style="color:green">
                    $<?=$row['price']?></big><br /><br />
                <input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(<?=$row['serial']?>)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><hr size="1" /></td>
    <? } ?>
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: can you provide some more code

Comment: What does `var_dump($row);` give you?

Comment: Most probably a notice as $row being undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undefined variables in an array normally means that you're trying to retrieve data from the array with an incorrect key.

Notice that:

- You have to iterate the database results with a loop, normally foreach or while, depending on the fetch method;
- The $row variable must contain the database results with associative keys, otherwise you can't access the data with a 'name' key;
- The key names must match the table's columns, and it is case sensitive.

  Let's have a basic example of how to work with data from a database (in this case, MySQL):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products`");

 //It's always a good idea to check if your query has returned any rows before proceeding.

 if (mysql_num_rows($query))
 {
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
      echo '
      <div><img src="'.$row['picture'].'" alt="" /></div>
      <div>
      <b>'.$row['name'].'</b><br />
      '.$row['description'].'<br />
      Price: <span style="color: green; font-size: 16px;">'.$row['price'].'</span>
      <br /><br />
      <input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="javascript: addtocart(\''.$row['serial'].'\');" />
      </div>
      ';

  }
}
```

Since your original question had little explanation and a lack of details and code, this is all I can do to help you.

Good luck.